# angular cli in intellij

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

everyone, i hope you can help me with this, i installed angular cli in my intellij `npm install -g @angular/cli` but when i go to the folder src/app its stay in load mode no file no folder from angular cli appear however in vscode everything work

i tried to uninstalled and installed intellij the new version and new version of angular, i searched i asked i can't find a solution

[image]

Comment: Disable all downloaded (not bundled) plugins in `Settings (Preferences) > Plugins`. Will the issue persist?

Answer (score 0):

The `-g` means `global`. This is a system-wide install option.

Leave it away and the module will appear in the place where you probably expect it.